# How to parse Dynamics CRM forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, crm

We have an integration with several CRM providers that let you create forms (HubSpot, SalesForce, Eloqua, Formspree, etc.).
These forms are then rendered in an iFrame alongside content that is created with our tool. Visual aspect of these forms is highly important, therefore we need to ensure their styling is consistent with the rest of the content created.
Most of these forms are either self-hosted HTML file or have an embed script.
For the former use-case, authors insert a reference to our JavaScript file, which allows us to strip styles from a form, inject our styling and communicate with our app (e.g. after form is successfully submitted, we can show the rest of the content, etc.). The latter use-case is similar, with the exception that our script is already present as the embedding happen on our end.

Our current workflow has some flaws:

- for our clients, this is time consuming and requires a technical person,
- each time a new form is created, we need to prepare styles for it,
- these forms are very dynamic in their HTML structure, which means styles are often not reusable,
- each time a form gets updated, we might not have styles prepared for it – which results as an un-styled form.

We’re now thinking of *alternative solutions*. One idea that comes to our mind is:

- Can we load these forms and parse their data model? Including:

  - headings and paragraphs,
  - labels and their corresponding inputs/selects/checkboxes, etc.
  - hidden inputs
- Can we then re-render form this form?

That would allow us to deal with forms data (then parsing becomes a problem) and fully control forms presentation and how they render (we take care of HTML and CSS). We reckon the above would need to happen on the client-side, as these CRM forms providers do some level of profiling, e.g. load different forms based on visitors cookie.
There are certain questions that arrive when thinking about the above idea, such as:

- How would we handle input validation?
- What happens when a new data type appears:

  - How do we parse the unknown?
  - How do we even know at the first place that we need to parse it?
- How to control (/check) whether data has been successfully passed to the CRM?

Is there any other alternatives we explore?

Comment: I can't speak for other platforms but my suggestion would be to make a managed package for Salesforce. That will give you direct database access and the ability to render lightning components or visualforce pages directly on the user's screen.

Comment: Have you explored the mentioned CRMs for possibility of API access instead of embedding their forms?

Comment: Hey. That would be one option, although we’re trying to make a platform agnostic solution where we can take the forms generated by CRMs, and apply our nice styles to them.